# Can i continuous to reindex the process after Elastic search reindex socket timeout

Tags: elasticsearch, timeout, reindex

I got the socket timeout exception when i reindex the data in elastic search. And half of data(50%) is reindex success. Anyone know i can continuous to reindex the remaining process (another 50%). I dont want to redo the whole process. Thanks.

Regards,
Ryan

Answer (score 1):

First of all, to run real reindex process, you should always run it Async with the *wait_for_completion=false* URL parameter.

You will get a task ID and can monitor the progress with

```
GET /_tasks/<task_id>
```

You will have to relaunch it from scratch, but already existing docs will not be updated or recreated.
It's not perfect but it will be quicker than your initial load.

Comment: @ryan1101 in my experience maybe 25% to 30% is quicker. you dont have any option. if you have this problem again I suggest to use reindex with query range time.